# How to set unique key on two columns and still have primary index with auto increment in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to set my table so that it won't allow insertion of a row if there's already row with the same values on two columns, but still keep the id column?

My table has columns - id(int), user_id(int), answer_id(int)

I want the id to autoincrement and unique.
And yet have user_id + answer_id as unique combination, so that there will never be two rows having same user_id and answer_id

How can I do that?

Comment: Exactly what is stopping you from doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ALTER TABLE t1 ADD UNIQUE KEY (user_id, answer_id)
```

Answer (score 2):

try

```
ALTER TABLE yourtable ADD UNIQUE KEY (user_id, answer_id)
```